# Opencart 3.0.2.0 Changes not reflectling on twig template

Tags: opencart-3

Have added new folder of custom theme in catalog/view/theme/template/customtheme  , herein addded header.twig in catalog/view/theme/template/customtheme/common folder. 
Also made changes in admin panel , in Extenions->Extensions->theme here selected the cutomtheme.
But the changes are not getting reflected in the frontend.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **OpenCart 3.x** there a feature to clear/refresh cache in the admin end
Try refreshing the cache and see if everything works.
[image]